# Issue with using svnant

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

I was provided with an ant build file from someone else which uses svnant and I'm having issues with getting it to work. I extracted out the part that is causing me problems into a separate file:

```
<project name="rev-check macrodef">
    <sequential>    
        <!-- ant contrib task definition -->
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
          <classpath>
            <pathelement location="C:/rms-it-apps/ant/taskdefs/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
          </classpath>
        </taskdef>

        <taskdef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" loaderref="svnant.loader">
          <classpath>
            <pathelement location="C:/rms-it-apps/ant/taskdefs/svnant-1.3.1/lib/svnant.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="C:/rms-it-apps/ant/taskdefs/svnant-1.3.1/lib/svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="C:/rms-it-apps/ant/taskdefs/svnant-1.3.1/lib/svnjavahl.jar"/>
           </classpath>
        </taskdef>
    </sequential>
    <!-- <svn svnkit="false" javahl="false"> -->
    <svn>
        <info target="C:/dev/workspace/rmsitpew/PEW/src" />
        <wcversion prefix="wc" path="C:/dev/workspace/rmsitpew/PEW/src" />
    </svn>
    <echo>Here 1</echo>
```

When I try to run it with just the `<svn>` tag I get the following output:

```
C:\dev\svnant>runant

C:\dev\svnant>C:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030\bi
n\ant.bat
Buildfile: C:\dev\svnant\build.xml
      [svn] Missing 'javahl' dependencies on the classpath !

BUILD FAILED
C:\dev\svnant\build.xml:19: Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn clie
nt

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I saw a suggestion to run it with the tag `<svn svnkit="false" javahl="false">` but then I get this output:

```
C:\dev\svnant>C:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030\bi
n\ant.bat
Buildfile: C:\dev\svnant\build.xml
      [svn] Deprecated attribute 'svnkit'. This attribute will disappear with SV
NANT 1.3.2. Use svnSetting instead.
      [svn] Deprecated attribute 'javahl'. This attribute will disappear with SV
NANT 1.3.2. Use svnSetting instead.
      [svn] svn: The path 'C:\dev\workspace\rmsitpew\PEW\src' appears to be part
 of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
      [svn] working copy rooted at 'C:\dev\workspace\rmsitpew'.
      [svn] Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy.
      [svn] <Info> failed.

BUILD FAILED
C:\dev\svnant\build.xml:18: Failed to set 'info' properties
```

Here are the contents of the directory C:\rms-it-apps\ant\taskdefs\svnant-1.3.1\lib:

```
04/05/2012  10:44 AM             3,010 GANYMED-LICENSE
04/05/2012  10:44 AM           244,831 ganymed.jar
04/05/2012  10:44 AM             2,800 JAVAHL-LICENSE
04/05/2012  10:44 AM               544 JNA-LICENSE
04/05/2012  10:44 AM           948,100 jna.jar
04/05/2012  10:44 AM             2,276 SEQUENCE-LICENSE
04/05/2012  10:44 AM            76,383 svnant.jar
04/05/2012  10:44 AM            11,935 SVNCLIENTADAPTER-LICENSE
04/05/2012  10:44 AM           215,757 svnClientAdapter.jar
04/05/2012  10:44 AM            89,412 svnjavahl.jar
04/05/2012  10:44 AM             2,695 SVNKit-LICENSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems:

- Your commandline client (svn) seems to be of an older version than the client you use to checkout/create your working copy. It is **essential** that the svn version you use in ant is EXACTLY the same as other svn tools you use on this working copy. The error suggests that you need to update the command line client to a 1.7 version
- javahl needs some strange libs to be installed in windows. See [here](http://deadmanwalking.wordpress.com/2007/07/28/ant-svn-task-svnant-and-javahl/) for details. Or ask the one who provided the task.
- you can ignore the deprecated warning at first. And fix it when everything works.

I'd suggest sticking to the commandline client or using svnkit.

[Here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html) you can find a general overview of all available tools, which you can use with the ant task.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up making it work with the command line client. I was using a too recent version of subclipse and once I downgraded the "appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 or greater" messages went away.

Comment: @opike yeah, thats a common problem :D